# How to write join fetch query with jooq?

Tags: java, jooq

Anyone knows how to write join fetch query with jooq ?
my code :

```
int oid=5;
Select<?> selectQuery = DSL_CONTEXT.select().from(TABLE_A)
      .join(TABLE_B).on(TABLE_A.PID.eq(TABLE_B.ID))
        .where(TABLE_A.OID.eq(oid))
        .orderBy(UPDATED.asc(), ID.asc())
        .seekAfter(val(offsetDateTime), val(id))
        .limit(50);
```

this results in : `select * from table_a join table_b` type of query. How to make it create a query of following type :

```
select * from table_a join fetch table b ...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get with jOOQ 3.11 out of the box functionality is using [`ResultQuery.fetchGroups()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchGroups-org.jooq.Table-org.jooq.Table-). On your query, call:

```
Map<TableARecord, Result<TableBRecord>> result = select.fetchGroups(TABLE_A, TABLE_B);
```